# Neural Network model error value is so big

Tags: r

[image: Error]

Why this error value is so big?
Is this a real error value?
Here is the code:

```
m3 <- neuralnet(price ~ neighbourhood_group + latitude + longitude + room_type + minimum_nights + number_of_reviews + calculated_host_listings_count + availability_365,
data = norm_train)
plot(m3)
```

Comment: You are using default setting for some important parameters like `hidden = 1`, `algorithm = "rprop+"`, `act.fct = "logistic"`. Use `hidden = 10` (though it is just indicative and requires optimisation) and see the error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the error value is the computed loss function on your dataset, I would first investigate the followings:

- Which one is the variability of your dependent variable? just to see whether such a high error could make sense.
- Which one is your output activation function? because if you have a sigmoid activation function for the output layer but you are trying to predict a quantity that can go from -infinity to +infinity you are making a mistake

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

There is no data to run your NN so it is hard to say precisely.

NN's can be quite fussy about how they like their inputs.

Perhaps check how have you scaled your variables.